# How to do queries for counts of matrix elements with values in given range

Tags: r, indexing, querying

I'm working on a project that is looking at regrowth of trees after a deforestation event. To simplify the data set for this question, I have a matrix (converted from data frame), which has 10 columns corresponding to years 2001-2010.

-1 indicates a change point in the data, when a previously forested plot was deforested. 1 indicated when a previously deforested region became forested. 0's indicate no change in state.

I found [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queries-counts-array-elements-values-given-range/) link which I think does what I need to do, except in python/c++. Since I did the rest of my analyses in R, I want to stick with it.

So I was trying to translate some of the code to R, but I've been having problems.

This is my sample data set. One of my alternative thoughts is that if I could identify the index of (-1) and then the index of 1, then I could subtract these two indices to get the difference (and then subtract 1 to account for factoring in the first index in the subtraction)

```
# Example data
head(tcc_change)

  id   2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  2008 2009  2010  
1  1      0     0     0     0     0    -1     0     0    1    0   
2  2      0     0     0    -1     0     0     1     0    0    0     
3  3      0     0     0    -1     0     0     0     1    0    0  
4  4      0    -1     0     0     0     0     1     0    0    0   
5  5      0     0     0     1     0     0    -1     1    0    0 

# Indexing attempt
tcc_change$loss_init <- apply(tcc_change, 1, function(x) match(-1, x[1:10], nomatch = 99)) 
tcc_change$gain <- apply(tcc_change, 1, function(x) match(1, x[1:10], nomatch=99))
```

This method has a lot of problems though. What if there's a 1 before a (-1), for example. I'd like to figure out a better way to do this analysis, similar to the logical structure in the link above, but I don't know how to do this in R.

Ideally I'd like to identify points where there was deforestation (-1) and then regrowth (1) and then count the zeroes in between. The number of zeroes in between would be posted to a new column. This would give me a better idea of how long it takes for a plot to become forested after a deforestation event. If there are no zeroes in between (like row 5), I would want the code to output '0'.

Comment: Can you just use `gain - loss_init -1`? if `gain` is before `loss_init` then set to `0`? `ifelse(gain > loss_init, gain-loss_init-1, 0)`

Comment: Thanks! This generally works for me. One question I have though, is what if there are more than one loss/gain events? For example [0,0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0]. I could see the indexing method not being able to handle this, is this correct?

Comment: good point. It also depends on how you are going to handle such situation, like do you want summation of those intervals or take the maximum? I can only think about how to handle simple case and will list below.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! This is a great start, and I appreciate you providing a function that works in most cases for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my function may only handle simple case. Hope that helps. 
First your code has some issues that when you search index, you include the `id` column as well (in `x[1:10]`). if you want to exclude that, can use `x[-1]` to exclude the first column, but the index will count from 2nd ones.

```
tcc_change$loss_init <- apply(tcc_change, 1, function(x) match(-1, x[1:10], nomatch = 99)) 
tcc_change$gain <- apply(tcc_change, 1, function(x) match(1, x[1:10], nomatch=99))
```

I adjusted your approach and first to get the `-1` index, then use `match` again to search index of `1` starting from the index of `-1`; then once I found that, can just minus 1 to get the number of intervals:

```
get_interval = function(x){
  init = match(-1, x[-1])
  interval = match(1, x[-(1:(init+1))]) - 1
  return(interval)
}

> apply(tcc_change, 1, get_interval)
[1] 2 2 3 4 0
```

Hope that helps.